# Spring integration processing using IntegrationFlows

Tags: spring-integration

I have 2 `IntegrationFlow`s which are linked together with JMS queue (each flow represents business phase), i.e. I use

> Jms.outboundAdapter(jmsConnectionFactory)
>                   .destination(jsmQueue)
>                   .get();

to send JMS message from one flow to another.

Second flow automatically picks up a message and continue processing, i.e. it depends on the first flow.
Second flow contains filter which sometimes stops processing.

Sometimes, what I need is to forcefully re-trigger processing in both flows, what can be achieved by sending manually created JMS message into channels of both flows by

> messagingTemplate.send(channel, new GenericMessage<>(luw))

The problem is sometimes, not always, 
if I send messages to both flows, processing clashes in second flow and I got optimistic lock exceptions

Is there a way to check that the processing was done all the way through both flows and after that to send a message into second flow?
Is there a better way how to approach things?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [retry advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) to the component that throws the optimistic locking exception.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I tried it, but as far as I know you can only wrap around component with advice. Is it possible to re-send the message into channel (beginning of the flow) with spring integration? Or should this be left to JMS broker?

Comment: Yes, if you use transactions, and let the exception be thrown to the JMS listener container, the broker will redeliver.